# Set post tags using tag ID

Tags: plugins, tags, id

I want to set post tags to a new value. Is there a way to use the **tag ID** to do it?
The `wp_set_post_tags` only accepts the **tag name** or an **array of tag names**.

```
<?php wp_set_post_tags( $post_ID, $tags, $append ) ?>
```

The reason why I want to set the tag using the `ID` is I don't want to make an additional call for getting the full tag object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-hierarchical terms (such as tags), you can pass either the term name or id. If you pass the id there is only one caveat: You must pass it as an integer, and it must be in an array. This is necessary because any non-array value passed will be converted to a string, which will be interpreted as a term name.

```
$tag = '5'; // Wrong. This will add the tag with the *name* '5'.
$tag = 5; // Wrong. This will also add the tag with the name '5'.
$tag = array( '5' ); // Wrong. Again, this will be interpreted as a term name rather than an id.

$tag = array( 5 ); // Correct. This will add the tag with the id 5.

wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $tag, $taxonomy );
```

This function will only work on the native post type.